# Rbind character vector to be first row in datatable r

Tags: r, datatable, rbind

I need to assign a character vector to be on the first row in a R datatable. But so far all my attempts gets it to be on the last. When I tried to give row number, it gives warnings about the amount of columns. This is the only on that works, but to the last row.

```
Character_vector <- colnames(DT)

DT_NEW <- rbind(DT,as.list(Character_vector, ))
DT_NEW
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different order of arguments inside `rbind` and proper way to construct a row with column names:

```
library(datatable)

DT = data.table(a=c("a1","a2","a3"),
            b=c("b1","b2","b3"),
            c=c("c1","c2","c3"))
Character_vector = colnames(DT)

result = rbind(setnames(do.call(data.table,
                                as.list(Character_vector)),
                        Character_vector),
               DT)
```

to get a frame like this:

```
> result
    a  b  c
1:  a  b  c
2: a1 b1 c1
3: a2 b2 c2
4: a3 b3 c3
```

To unwrap all that happens is an `rbind` of a single row of column names and the original frame `DT` in the that order:

```
single_row_with_col_names = do.call(data.table, as.list(Character_vector))
setnames(single_row_with_col_names, Character_vector)
result = rbind(single_row_with_col_names,
               DT)
```